# How to count the number of nonzero in the eigen::Tensor<T,2>

Tags: c++, eigen

If I use the sum of bool tensor, the reuslt is 1 forever

```
Eigen::Tensor<int,2> my_rankx (3,3);
my_rankx.setValues(
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {0, 0, 0},
    {11, 12, 0}
});

auto number_matrix = (my_rankx.constant(static_cast<int>(0))==my_rankx);
cout<<number_matrix.sum()<<endl; // result of cout is 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`(my_rankx.constant(0) == my_rankx)` is a tensor of `bool`s, and adding `bool`s together results in either `false` or `true`, which are converted to `0` and `1` respectively.  (Incidentally, the `static_cast<int>(0)` in the question is redundant because `0` is of type `int`.)

You can use [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) along with [`data()`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?fileviewer=file-view-default#markdown-header-scalar-data-and-const-scalar-data-const) instead:

```
std::cout << std::count(my_rankx.data(), my_rankx.data() + my_rankx.size(), 0)
          << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a little bit late but I ran into a similar problem and used a solution which differs from the current answer.

The following worked fine for me:
`number_matrix.array().cast<int>().sum()`

Casting the elements directly into an integer will avoid the 'wrong' sum over the booleans.